# Is there a way to pass Django-pagination an integer

Tags: python, django, pagination

Using the `django-pagination` lib, I like using the `autopaginate` tag and then `{% paginate %}` in my template because it automatically formats the page numbering nicely.

However, the form it needs is

```
{% autopaginate object_list %}
```

But I wanted to know if I could pass it an integer, ie. the number of hits. In this case, the number of hits is quite large, and converting that to a list of integers (ex: 5 -> [0,1,2,3,4]) will crash my app since it's hundreds of thousands of items long in some cases.

So does anyone know if it can accept an integer?

Comment: This template requires the list, I think integer may be not works. You can advise the length of the list, only return a subset of the whole list to reduce the numbers. And if need the other numbers, just reload to extend the list.

Comment: What do you want the integer to do? Set the page, set the number of objects per-page, ...?

Comment: I want to show the page list so you can go to the next page or previous page or page 10 , for example.  I like how paginate does all that Automatically when you pass it a list of values.

Comment: Basically I want it to set the number of total entries. For example if I have 1000 entries it will paginate based on that and based on a value I set for the number of entries per page.